# woocommerce badge not showing up in the woocommerce widget

Tags: wordpress, web, woocommerce

I am experienced with Wordpress, PHP etc but just finding my way around WooCommerce and looking for advice. Any changes i made in shop page like adding sale badge or new badge it doesn't affect the wooCommerce slider widget
It seems like i did nothing i don't know how
You can check my www.gotezkar.com , and check the shop page and the home page slider i'm really stuck and dun know what to do

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins available for this product customizer or product designer option.

**Free plugin:**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/zakeke-interactive-product-designer/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-designer/

**Premium Plugin:**

https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-conditional-checkout-fields/20668577?gclid=CjwKCAiAj-_xBRBjEiwAmRbqYpxJZ9xAlwBMweKZjXZDpdi3xapwgjvpJwAHJ2KuwFSrrfSD-RCKNxoCuUoQAvD_BwE

If you are looking for an option that allows the user to enter their NAME in a field and to print it in the product, you can also achieve it using Advanced Custom Fields by creating a custom field for product detailed page and use it.